# angular not updating

Tags: angularjs

The attribute on the view doesn't updating.
When I click on the remove image, then comes a popup model.

the attribute `{{name}}` is not updating and `setName` has updated the name...

Comment: Please post additional code, ie: your controller code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything should be in the scope of controller:

```
<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
<td width="40px">
       <img src="~/Images/Remove3.ico"  ng-click="setName(member.naamNL)" alt="remove" />
</td>
</div>
```